# How can I estimate the number of rows and columns in a chess pattern?

Tags: image-processing

I am working on some code for estimating the position and orientation of a camera.
From an image taken by the camera I require that the user select lower left interior corner: green, the lower right interior corner: blue and the upper left interior corner: red:
[image]

Knowing the number of columns and rows I then calculate the approximate position of each interior corner from these points.
Using a window around the approximate corners I find the corners more exactly.
This works fine.

However I cannot change to another target with a different number of columns and rows without changing my code.

Is there some simple and robust way I can find the number of columns and rows?

The image may be rotated but the skew should be small and the x and y scale known.

We can assume that the number of rows and number of columns are within the range: [2,50].

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the corners indicated in the image this is relatively easy:
Get the intensity profile of a line a little to the left of the red-green connecting line and count the number of minimums (=number of black square) to get the number of rows. Do the same for the green-blue line to get the number of columns.